# Disallowed key characters in alert of ajax response

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

```
  var onSuccess=function(data)
  {
       alert(data);
       obj=JSON.parse(data);
       var response=obj.response;
   }
```

the above is my javascript file and next is the how i am sending the response

```
         $hash=$this->db->query($query);
         if ($hash->num_rows() > 0)
             $valid['response']= 0;
        else
             $valid['response']= 1;
         return($valid_user);
```

the alert box is showing "disallowed key characters" and even i had checked config file in codeigniter .... everything is correct as mentioned everywhere

```
  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Comment: What was the URL of your AJAX call? (including the query string, if any)